# System.Diagnostics.Process.StandardOutput returning bad string that have accentuation

Tags: c#, wpf, shell, process

I have this code that execute shell commands:

```
public void ExecuteShellCommand(string _FileToExecute, string _CommandLine, ref string _outputMessage, ref string _errorMessage)
    {
        //Set process variable.
        //Provides access to local and remote processes and enables you to start and stop local system processes.
        System.Diagnostics.Process _Process = null;
        try
        {
            _Process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            _Process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";

            //Invokes the cmd process specifying the command to be executed.

            var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR", true);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR", false);

            string _CMDProcess = string.Format(culture, @"{0}\cmd.exe",
                                               new object[] { Environment.SystemDirectory });

            //Pass executing file to cmd (Windows command interpreter) as a arguments
            // /C tells cmd we want it to execute the comand that follows, then exit.
            string _Arguments = string.Format(culture, "/C {0}",
                                              new object[] { _FileToExecute });

            //Pass any command line parameters for execution
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_CommandLine))
            {
                _Arguments += string.Format(culture, " {0}",
                                            new object[] { _CommandLine, culture });
            }

            var _ProcessStartInfo =
                new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(_CMDProcess, _Arguments);

            //Sets a value indicating not to start the process in a new window. 
            _ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            //Sets a value indicating now to use the operating system shell to start the process.
            _ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            //Sets the value that indicates the output/input/error of an aplication is written to the Process.
            _ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            _ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            _ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            _Process.StartInfo = _ProcessStartInfo;

            //Starts a process resource and associates it with a Process component.
            _Process.Start();

            //Instructs the Process component t wait indefitely for the associated process to exit.
            _errorMessage = _Process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            _Process.WaitForExit();

            //Instructs the Process component to wait indefinitely for the associated process to exit.

            _outputMessage = _Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            _Process.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Win32Exception _Win32Exception)
        {
            //Error
            MessageBox.Show("Win32 Exception caught in process: " + _Win32Exception.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception _Exception)
        {
            //Error
            MessageBox.Show("Exception caught in process: " + _Exception.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            _Process.Close();
            _Process.Dispose();
            _Process = null;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that my system language is `pt-BR`, the output:

```
_outputMessage = _Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

returns broken strings:

Returned string: "`Autentica‡Æo`"

Expected string: "`Autenticação`"

But if I use the same command inside CMD, everything returns okay, no erros or broken strings...

**What is wrong with my code?**

---

**EDIT:**

I'm trying execute shell commands via code. Using cmd.exe + arguments.

---

**Working:**

```
_ProcessStartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(850);
```

Now, the encoding matches.

Comment: does the child process set the console encoding?

Comment: I'm not changing anything, the output uses the `System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding`...

Comment: SBCS stands for _Single Byte Character set_, in which case combining characters such as çã are going to break badly.

Comment: I'm trying to use:

`_ProcessStartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();`
or UTF-8, UTF-7, UTF32, nothing works...

Comment: @Mgetz Well, thanks for trying to help. I'm gonna let this thing down for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [code page 850](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850), the MS-Dos code page for Portuguese.  ç = 0x87, ã = 0xc6.
Your program is currently incorrectly using [code page 1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_1252), 0x87 = ‡, 0xc6 = Æ.

Comment: Thanks, Now I'm trying to convert 1252 to 850 using `Encoding.GetEncoding(850)` and this code http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdcak6ye.aspx